# "ristretto" slideshow in fullscreen

Tags: xubuntu, ristretto

I am using xubuntu atm and my biggest issue is, that ristretto show pictures in 100% zoom.
When I run a slideshow, I want it to expand to full screen.
I can only enable that for one picture at a time, and this gets reset if I switch to antother picture.

Comment: My absolutely preffered kind of answer is, how to enable that within ristretto. An alternative would be an image viewer with few depencies but nice integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use Ristretto (a little at my Linux life start only) and people often suggest "eliminate this utility" (quote). And despite this fact if I right figure out you need to know where exist such checkbox alike first at **[Ristretto Menu > Edit > Preferences](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/ristretto/preferences)**:

[image]

I think more settings for Ristretto you can find at Settings Editor ([**xfconf GUI**](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/editor)), and you can see ***ristretto*** exists at settings channels list:

[image]

---

Alternatively I do not know what to suggest.
If I'll needed to use XFCE I'll chosen **Feh** which also lightweight also image also viewer however Feh it is "barebone" image viewer and can be a bit difficult for plain user.

So, look if interesting [**Feh**](http://linuxbrit.co.uk/software/feh/)

Hope it help you.

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work  on my xfce 4.12, it just opens risettro in full screen, with a tiny image in the middle. I can zoom to fit, but the next image doesn't work. #2 didn't have any options of risettro. @didn't try the third.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was looking for this in ristretto, but I gave up. Don't know how to set stretching image to screen without clicking it at every image. Shotwell also was beyond my skills.

However, I may found satisfying solution for your needs.

To create presentation with stretched and fitted images simply run `vlc` (which I consider to be basic video player on every computer) hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and add image files you want to be in slide show.

Tricky thing is duration of single slide: hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> mark **`Show settings` ⇒ `All`** and then go to: **`Input/Codecs` ⇒ `Demuxers` ⇒ `Image` ⇒ `Duration is seconds`** (by default 10 seconds).

If you want to infinitely repeat presentation, just hit loop button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me. Shotwell has removed the slideshow feature. At least, I can't find it in 16.04. And EOG can only delay for up to 90 seconds between images.

Comment: If you haven't found another solution, the package mirage is a huge upgrade over rissetro, with the same ui.

Answer (score 1):

Settled on mirage; it has features of risttreto plus a lot more customizability, including remembering last settings - both on next image, and on next open.

```
package-manager install mirage
```

Tried viewnoir, but it no thumbnail preview is a dealbreaker.